# segmentation fault in number of prime up to N(N>10000)

Tags: c

I am having a segmentation fault on my program seeking the number of prime numbers up to N.

I used a dynamic linked list for the prime numbers to test N for efficiency.

The problem is it works when N<=17508. It fails for greater N. Especially when I add up the print out, it always have segmentation fault. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct prime{
long value;
struct prime *next;
}prime;

long numofprime(long n)
{
long a, b, c;

prime *head, *p1, *p2, *p3;
int flag;

if(n<0)
n=-n;

if(n<2)
    return 0;
else if(n==2)
    return 1;
else
{/*creat linked list*/
   p1=(prime *)malloc(sizeof(prime));
   p1->value=2;
   p1->next=NULL;
   p2=p1;
   head=p1;

        b=1;
        for(a=3;a<=n;a+=2)
        {
            flag=0;
            p3=head;
            while(p3!=NULL)
            {
                c=p3->value;
                if(a%c==0)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
                p3=p3->next;
            }

            if(flag==0)
            {/*add prime number to the linked list*/
                p1=(prime *)malloc(sizeof(prime));
                p1->value=a;
                p2->next=p1;
                p2=p1;
                b++;
            }
        }

        c=0;
        while(head!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%5ld ", head->value);
            if(c%15==0) printf("\n");
            head=head->next;
            c++;
        }

        return b;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

long n;
long np;

if(argc<2)
{
    printf("Please input the max num!\n");
    exit(0);
}
else if(argc>2)
{
    printf("Too many arguments!\n");
    exit(0);
}
else
    n=strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    np=numofprime(n);

    printf("\n\nthere are %ld primes < n!\n", np);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: When you run in a debugger, where does it say the crash is? Do all variables involved in that expression look okay to you?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: It crashes at line       long numofprime(long n)
     {

Comment: When `N` goes above 17508, how many nodes have you allocated then? You are aware of that memory allocation can fail, and `malloc` retrurn `NULL`? You need to check for that. Also, [in C don't cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Upon 17508, there are 2014 prime numbers, 2014 nodes in the linked list.
Thanks  Joachim and Jens

Answer (score 3):

As you allocate a new item for the linked list, always set the pointer to the `next` item to `NULL`. Otherwise, the end of the linked list cannot be detected, an undefined behavior appears and segmentation faults are possible.

For instance :

```
        {/*add prime number to the linked list*/
            p1=malloc(sizeof(prime));
            if(p1==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"failed to allocate\n");exit(1);}
            p1->value=a;
            p1->next=NULL; ///this new line here
            p2->next=p1;
            p2=p1;
            b++;
        }
```

Moreover, do not forget to `free()` the memory at the end of the function. Doing `head=head->next` to print the linked list will not ease this operation since going back is not possible : the pointer to the beginning of the linked list is lost. Always keep a pointer to the beginning of a linked list somewhere !

Comment: Good point. Is this code time complexity o(N(logN)? I have no knowledge about this.

Comment: There are about ln(n) prime numbers below n. So the total number of operations is about \sum_{n=1}^N(ln(n)). And this sum is about N.ln(N)-N. So the complexity of your program is O(N.ln(N)). Notice that you can `break` the while loop as soon as `p3->value` is above `sqrt(a)`. It will not change the complexity, but it might divide the computation time by 2.